# Word for someone who is clever and smart but book-dumb?

Tags: single-word-requests, epithet-requests

What is a good adjective for someone clever/smart but book dumb?

Comment: Please include a sentence where this word/idiom/phrase or expression could be used. E.g. *Bob's sharp as a tack, but he's _______ when it comes to books/general knowledge*. OR *Despite being a bright kid, Bob has never been a ______ at school*

Comment: What does "book dumb" mean?

Comment: @TrevorD  [Book dumb](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BookDumb) a bit of a clichè really in my experience.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Not an expression I've ever heard of! (My father owned a bookshop, so I'm the opposite: "book clever" ??! :-)

Comment: Maybe *street smart*.

Comment: The words "streetsmart" and "streetwise" don't necessarily mean being smart. They point out a person's ability to deal with difficult situations on city streets. Hence, the word "street".

Comment: Unschooled or unread sometimes refers to those otherwise capable.

Answer (score 1):

[Practically minded](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/practically-minded)

Someone who is a good problem-solver, but not as good, or not interested in the theoretical side.

Comment: I disagree: "practically minded" does **not** mean being a good problem solver, and the definition you've given us the link to doesn't mention problem solving at all. Someone who is practically minded might for example be good with tools but not be the sharpest tool in the shed. Practical does not equal clever.

Answer (score 1):

[Savvy](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/savvy)

Someone who is practically knowledgeable and shrewd.

Comment: Savvy doesn't indicate that someone is necessarily "book dumb".

Answer (score 1):

Someone who is street smart, but not necessarily academically intelligent, could be called any of the following, depending on the specific usage you need: adroit, sagacious, streetwise, shrewd,  sly, capable, artful, canny, clever, cunning, practical, crafty, seasoned, wily, astute, perceptive, or quick-witted. 
         I think "worldy" could also be used, as it describes a preferred concern with tangible and material matters, rather than those which are intellectual and spiritual. "Glib" would be acceptable if you were describing one's manner of speech, specifically. "Boorish" could work, as well, but I feel that it's probably not as concise a word option as the rest, since it refers more to mannerisms and civility than mental intelligence. Just check the specific definitions of these examples in any online dictionary and I'm sure you can find whichever one most closely fits what you want to say.

        Also, check out this online thesaurus: https://www.powerthesaurus.org/, which is extensive, and extremely helpful as a starting point when you can't think of just the word you need.

Comment: As an additional thought, if you want to focus more on the "book dumb" but still mentally sharp, aspect of the idea, you might try starting off in the thesaurus I linked, with a search for synonyms of "uneducated", or for antonyms of "intellectual". For that, you can manage on your own, I provided plenty of examples.